# Does google use transliteration when crawling page URLs and indexing them?

Tags: seo, google-search, search

In a generic search Google understands transliteration and if I wrote some words using Latin letters but in a non-English language ( for instance phrase "red cat" in Russian using transliteration will be "krasnii kot" ) will Google suggest this phrase in Cyrillic and do a search in Russian texts?

Thinking in terms of a web shop and that the URLs for product pages contain transliteration, will Google index them as well?

Comment: Since Google returns completely different search results for красный Кот and krasnyy kot (this is the transliteration that Google gives), I would guess that Google treats them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Google classifies transliteration of language and actual characters of a language as two different things. Another common example is the greek language. A common practice by many users online is to write greek words but transliterate so they can use a western character set and keyboard to do it. Take the following...

papou and παππούς. They both mean grandfather in greek but are treated as two separate words for the purposes of a Google search. The first one I wrote using my standard western keyboard which was easy to do but to be able to produce the second one I actually needed to load up a greek on screen keyboard to be able to access greek character sets.